# Calling a variable from a data frame, the name of which is stored as character

Tags: r

So basically I'm using a For loop, that loops between names that are stored in a vector(partners) and returns a the names as data frames containing specific data. The code goes something like this

```
for (i in partners) {
     #Code that returns the names as data frames
```

For the next statement in the for loop, I need to manipulate the variables in the data frames, so I need something like

```
    i$Volume <- #manipulation
}

#i[, "Volume"] is also not working
```

How do I call the data frame and a specific variable in it?

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the data frames in `partners` exist in the workspace?

Comment: @Benjamin I think so. Because when I run the loop without the additional command, I can see the data frames in `partners` stored as objects in the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I believe this would work

```
for (i in partners){
  df <- get(i)
  df$Volume <- identity(df$Volume) # or something
  assign(i, df)
}
```

I should also add a comment that this may get easier to manage if you put your data frames into a list, and apply a function to the data frames.  You could get all of your data frames into a list using `mget(partners)`, for example.

```
dframes <- mget(partners)

manip_fun <- function(df){
  df$Volume <- identity(df$Volume)
  df
}

lapply(dframes, manip_fun)
```

Comment: Thanks!
Works without the identity function though

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to know if there is a reverse function of get? Like function(object) would return the name of an object as characters

Comment: That will work, though carries some risk.  That is simply translating the expression to a string, and is indifferent to whether or not `object` actually exists.  If you need something a little more robust, you could use `varname_string <- function(x, envir = .GlobalEnv, ...){
  name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if (exists(name, envir = envir, ...)){
    name
  } else {
    stop(sprintf("Could not find object `%s`", name))
  }
}`